# Can't use fillMaxWidth or fillParentMaxWidth in LazyGrid - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create a LazyVerticalGrid with items that have a height as high as the LazyVerticalGrid. The LazyVerticalGrid should have a height of fillMaxSize().
When I use fillMaxHeight in the item, the items are hidden.
I tried using fillParentMaxHeight but this is not available in LazyGridItemScope
How can I create items with a height of something like fillMaxHeight()

My Code:

```
LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(2), modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            .fillMaxSize(),content = {
            items(count = 100){
                val cardColor = Color((0..255).random(),(0..255).random(),(0..255).random())
                Card(modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(4.dp)
                    .fillMaxHeight(3f), colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = cardColor)) {
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: I think @JokeyGrAp you need to use ```VerticalPager``` rather using ```LazyVerticalGrid```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You @Ali Elgamal :) but I fixed it by using BoxWithConstraints like this:

```
BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp).fillMaxSize()) {
            var boxWithConstraintsScope = this
            LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(2), modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .onSizeChanged {
                },content = {
                items(count = 100){
                    val cardColor = Color((0..255).random(),(0..255).random(),(0..255).random())
                    Card(modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(4.dp)
                        .height(boxWithConstraintsScope.maxHeight-8.dp), colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = cardColor)) {
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you might use onSizeChanged function in modifier to get the size and set that size in items by modifier, do not forget to make this variable in remember

code:

```
var gridHeight by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
val density = LocalDensity.current.density

LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(2), modifier = Modifier
        .weight(1f)
        .fillMaxSize()
        .onSizeChanged {
           gridHeight = it.height / density.toInt()
        },content = {
        items(count = 100){
            val cardColor = Color((0..255).random(),(0..255).random(),(0..255).random())
            Card(modifier = Modifier
                .padding(4.dp)
                .height(gridHeight.dp), colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = cardColor)) {
            }
        }
    })
```

i hope this what you want :)

- i have noticed you used fraction=3f in fillMaxHeight(3f), this function take value from 0 to 1, however it would not send any error message as it would put the value in this range 0..1 automatically

Comment: Thank you @Ali Elgamal but with this method the items are not exactly as high as the LazyColumn itself

Comment: okay i figure out the problem is that the height given as integer not dp (density pixels). edit the update height as this -> gridHeight = it.height / density.toInt(), where density -> val density = LocalDensity.current.density

Comment: Yes thats better but the items are still not exactly as high as the lazycolumn

Comment: I tried it and it works, are you sure not the same. Try to log the height of lazycolumn and card to make sure they are not equal